How to get USB Speaker on Raspberry Pi to run at Start-up?
I am using an external USB stereo speaker for my Raspberry Pi 3 B+. Here is the product: https://www.adafruit.com/product/3369
I've set up the speaker properly and tested to make sure it works. However, I am having some trouble with the code I am running on start-up. I am running this code on the .bashrc file so it auto runs every time the Pi boots up:
from espeak import espeak

#code to set-up buttons

#if button_pressed:
   espeak.synth("button pressed")

When I press run for this code on Thonny, it works fine. However, when I press the button after start-up using the bashrc file I get this error:
jotigokaraju07@raspberrypi:~ $ ALSA lib pcm_asym.c:105:(_snd_pcm_asym_open) capture slave is not defined
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1369:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.0.pcm.front.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5703:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1369:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.0.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5703:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1369:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.0.pcm.surround40.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory


ALSA lib conf.c:5703:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock

ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused


ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:1001:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1369:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.0.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=6,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5703:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958:{AES0 0x6 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x0 AES3 0x2 CARD 0}
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib pcm_asym.c:105:(_snd_pcm_asym_open) capture slave is not defined
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:999:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Expression 'paInvalidSampleRate' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2048
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_InitialConfigure( &self->playback, outParams, self->primeBuffers, hwParamsPlayback, &realSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2721
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Configure( stream, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, &inputLatency, &outputLatency, &hostBufferSizeMode )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2842
wave_open_sound > Pa_OpenStream : err=-9997 (Invalid sample rate)
jotigokaraju07@raspberrypi:~ $ ^C

I tried rebooting the alsa-utils, I also made sure all the speaker congfigs were right. I think the problem might be that the speaker attempts to start before its actually set-up on boot-up, but I'm not sure how to fix?
